# stop when one batch fails from one machine

Tags: batch-file

I have two batch files located on two different machines which done one task.

Lets say first batch is on machine A, second batch is on machine B.

I want that if one batch fails on machine A fails, then second batch on machine B should skip.

Because there is no point running second batch file if first one fails in my script.

Any thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Which protocols do you have for interaction between these two machines?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WAITFOR

In machine B, to wait for 2min to script A to finalize

```
WAITFOR /T 120 mySignal
IF errorlevel 1 (
    Echo Script A failed
)
```

And in machine A, if everything ok, send signal to machine B to continue

```
WAITFOR /S machineB /SI mySignal
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the Machine A batch file fails.

If the exe in batch A exits then you can use PSexec to check the tasklist on Machine A and branch in batch B if it is not running.

However if the EXE just doesn't respond then it will still be in the tasklist and you will have to detect if it is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `IF ERRORLEVEL` construction.

Your first batch file should return special codes if everithing is ok (for example, `EXIT 0`) and if there is a problem (for example, `EXIT 1`).

And your script will check this error code before run of second batch file. It will look like this: `IF ERRORLEVEL 0 CALL SECOND.BAT`

Comment: Would you explain more? like where to add IF ERRORLEVEL as I said my script span across servers, if I add IF ERRORLEVEL in first batch on machine A, how machine B recognizes the error status? please explain  as I am a bit new to scripting.

Comment: Ok, I've extended the answer.

Comment: I was sure you run these batch files one-by-one from another one script on one machine. Now it looks like it is wrong. Please describe you problem more detailed.